# How can I group by date interval in the two columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have table like this:

[image]

[image]

I need to find date value of `file` column and group by date-file date values interval . I tried like this:

```
select date,regexp_substr(FILE, '[[:DIGIT:]]{12}') FILEDATE from table
```

It's show date and file date. How can I group by date-file date interval like this?:

[image]

Comment: what this count is ? Do you mean for given date how many total no of files are there like: 3 files are there for date 5 on above example

Comment: Count is row. I have 3 rows (date - filedate)=5 days.

Comment: I didn't got; can you elaborate it more with some example referring above data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values in the `"DATE"` and `"FILE"` columns are going to have the same times then you can use:

```
SELECT   "DATE" - TO_DATE( REGEXP_SUBSTR( "FILE", '\d{14}', 1, 1 ), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS' ) AS "INTERVAL"
         COUNT(1) AS "COUNT"
FROM     TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY "DATE" - TO_DATE( REGEXP_SUBSTR( "FILE", '\d{14}', 1, 1 ), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS' );
```

If they will have different times then wrap the `"INTERVAL"` and `GROUP BY` expressions in a `CEIL()` (or `FLOOR()`) function - alternately you can `TRUNC()` the dates before subtracting; like this:

```
SELECT   TRUNC( "DATE" ) - TRUNC( TO_DATE( REGEXP_SUBSTR( "FILE", '\d{14}', 1, 1 ), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS' ) ) AS "INTERVAL"
         COUNT(1) AS "COUNT"
FROM     TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY TRUNC( "DATE" ) - TRUNC( TO_DATE( REGEXP_SUBSTR( "FILE", '\d{14}', 1, 1 ), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS' ) );
```